# cocos2d and box2d: camera rotation

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

i have a similar situation to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655892/cocos2d-top-down-camera-view-with-rotation). I want to keep the camera with the player in the center and the rotation of the player.

But i'm using box2d so i can't rotate the environment and keep the player static. how can i do this with cocos2d?

i only have code for the rotation, and i'm sure it's pretty wrong:

```
self.rotation = car.body->GetAngle()*(180.0/M_PI);
```

heres a bad sketch:
[image: bad sketch]

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has a lot of information on moving backgrounds.

[How to move background in cocos 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395959/how-to-move-background-in-cocos-2d)

What you need to do is create a CCLayer, and rotate the layer.  That would be the best approach as long as the screen shot above is accurate.

Here is a more detailed link with code.
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/22376